# No result when animating styles in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using the following code to animate the margin-top CSS style of a div with an id of "div".

HTML:

```
<div id="div">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <button id="trigger">
        Change Margin
    </button>
</div>
```

Javascript (In the head section):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("trigger").mouseup(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        marginTop: "-20px"
    });
});
</script>
```

However, when I click the button, nothing happens... Why is that?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLx5U/

Comment: Use CSS `transition` instead of jQuery `animate`. Trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)`trigger` is an `id` ,your missing '#' in your jquery code.
2) wrap your jquery code in `document.ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#trigger").mouseup(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        marginTop: "-20px"
    });
});
});
```

Please see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/Rssb6/2/).

Comment: if your using `document.ready` in your fiddle, you should turn "onLoad" to "No wrap - in <head>" on the left, otherwise it's really overkill

Comment: @myfunkyside : Oops!!. thanks did not notice that.i LL update it

Answer (score 1):

First, as said in other answers, your code is missing `#` inside the jQuery element selector.

Also, I highly recommend avoiding javascript animations: **Use CSS transitions when possible**, it's less buggy and easier to manipulate. [**Here's @Pdk1303's fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/Rssb6/4/) modified to use CSS transitions and class toggling, so if you click the button twice the margin will return to the default.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#trigger").on("click", function(){
        $("div").toggleClass("lessMargin");
    });
});
```